# Как правильно сделать POST запрос Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, post, api, retrofit

Мне очень нужна помощь.. Не знаю как сделать POST запрос по этому API: http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/1?format=api
В документации ничего. Вроде необходимо только rate, text, username. Но не понимаю. Делаю так:

```
Rate rateObject = new Rate(rate, comment, new CreatedBy(username));
            Call<Rate> call = service.sendProductRev(product_id, rateObject);
```

Api интерфейс:

```
POST("api/reviews/{product_id}")
Call<Rate> sendProductRev(@Path("product_id") String product_id,
                          @Body Rate review);
```

Но возвращает в respomce это:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, url=http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/1}
```

Не понимаю как правильно сделать POST запрос тут.

(POST запрос возможно там делать. Добавление данных)

UPD: [Rate and CreatedBy](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1740789a35694ba3e6e9bd847b356c1d)

Нет. С сервером всё ок. 
Нашёл доки: 
POST /api/reviews/{product_id}/-постить отзыв о продукте с идентификатором. Пример запроса:

```
{ "rate": 5, 
"text": "Lorem"
}
```

Пример ответа:

```
{ "review_id": 5 }
```

Comment: Добавьте код классов `Rate` и `CreatedBy`. А вариант, что на сервере что-то не работает, не возможен? И без документации это гадания на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @eugeneek добавил

Comment: Запрос с этими параметрами не работает и без ретрофита. Так что дело в сервере. Похоже он ожидает что-то ещё в запросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы были на стороне сервера. Спасибо кто помогал